# Import, join, and name multiple files in Pyton (thesis project)

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

For my thesis project I need to import and join 117 .json files into one dataframe. Manually it works but I can't figure out a loop. Another problem is that the features need the have filename in the data frame.

Basically I need to automate this process below:

```py
df_aa = pd.read_json(r'path')

df_aa.columns = ['Time', 'Active_adresses']
#df_aa.head()
#df_aa.tail()

df_tf = pd.read_json(r'path')

df_tf.columns = ['Time', 'Total_fees']
#df_tf.head()
#df_tf.tail()

df_tf.merge(df_aa, on='Time', how='left')
```

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MycQp.jpg)

Anyone who can help me? I don't have much programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

Find a common pattern by which you split/chunk all of the files for your loop to do the single action of loading. If there's no specific treatment required, use

```py
from glob import glob
print(list(glob("*.json")))  # put to list if you want to print it

for item in glob("*.json"):
    do_your_loading()
```

to get all of the files, then load them one by one (or via an aggregating func, if there's some in the library) and then join the dataframes into a single one, if necessary.

For the name in the dataframe simply add a new column after the initial chunk loading will contain on all of the rows the filename (from glob or otherwise).

For example:

```py
dataframes = {}
for item in glob("*.json"):
    df_aa = pd.read_json(r'path')
    df_aa.columns = ['Time', 'Active_adresses']
    #df_aa.head()
    #df_aa.tail()

    # put the filename to a new column
    df_aa = df_aa.assign(filename=item)

    df_tf = pd.read_json(r'path')
    df_tf.columns = ['Time', 'Total_fees']
    #df_tf.head()
    #df_tf.tail()
    df_tf.merge(df_aa, on='Time', how='left')

    # put the filename to a new column
    df_tf = df_tf.assign(filename=item)

    dataframes[item] = {"aa": df_aa, "tf": df_tf}

dataframes["my-filename.json"]["aa"].head()
dataframes["my-filename.json"]["tf"].head()
```

Comment: Well, yes, the `glob()` is meant to give you the filenames for loading over which you need to iterate. The loading is up to you. By joining you need to either have some common column or you concatenate everything to the end while having in the joint dataframe all of the columns from all of the JSONs and in the result `None` values after the merging.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try this now :)